# Domain Model Object to View Model Object in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework-5, automapper

I want to use view model for displaying instead of domain model. I have got these view models classes:

```
public class ArticleDescriptionViewModel
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
}

public class HomePage
{
    public List<ArticleDescriptionViewModel> Articles { get; set; }
}
```

In the domain model i have got:

```
public class ArticleDescription
{     
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
}
```

And this service method:

```
public List<ArticleDescription> GetArticlesDescription()
{
     var articleDescription= from a in _ctx.Articles
                             select new ArticleDescription 
                             { Title = a.Title, DateCreated = a.DateCreated };
     return articleDescription.ToList(); 
}
```

in the controller i want to match my list inside of my view model class with the list returned by my domain model class.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    HomePage HomePageInstance = new HomePage();
    HomePageInstance.Articles  = _repo.GetArticlesDescription();
    return View(HomePageInstance);
}
```

I have got an error:

> "Cannot implicitly convert type System.Collections.Generic.List (DBayonaCode.Domain.Services.Models.ArticleDescription)' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List(DBayonaCode.Models.ArticleDescriptionViewModel)'"

But these two classes are equivalent? I am doing something wrong. I appreciate your help?

Comment: Both class are **not** equivalent - they might have the same property names names but they are not the same classes. You need to convert `ArticleDescription` to `ArticleDescriptionViewModel`. Use a linq `.Select(x => new ArticleDescriptionViewModel() { ...` or look at using tools such as [automapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will cheack Automapper option, however one question remains: Is it good approach what i am doing here, trying to get this separation of concerns?, you know, i could make reference to my domain class in my controller to create a list of type <my domain class> to receive the results and that's it. I would not need to map these two classes. (domain class - view class).?Is there another better approach?

Comment: You approach is correct. You controller is responsible for getting the data model(s) from the service and mapping it to the view model. While you could use the domain model in the view, its always better to use a view model to display/edit only what you want, to apply validation attributes etc.

Comment: Thanks. That's clear now. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ArticleDescription` and `ArticleDescriptionViewModel` are two different types, so there's no implicit conversion between them. You need to map your *Domain Model object* to your *View Model object*, you can do that either manually or with a tool like **[AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/)**.

You could write extension methods like these to do the mapping:

```
public static class Mappings
{
    public static ArticleDescriptionViewModel ConvertToView(this ArticleDescription article)
    {
        // Mapping Code
        // return new ArticleDescriptionViewModel { ... }
    }

    public static List<ArticleDescriptionViewModel> ConvertToViews(this List<ArticleDescription> articles)
    {
        List<ArticleDescriptionViewModel> articleViews = new List<ArticleDescriptionViewModel>();

        foreach (ArticleDescription article in articles)
        {
            articleViews.Add(article.ConvertToView())
        }
        return articleViews;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It works perfect. however one question remains: Is it good approach what i am doing here, trying to get this separation of concerns?, you know, i could make reference to my domain class in my controller to create a list of type <my domain class> to receive the results and that's it. I would not need to map these two classes. (domain class - view class).?Is there another better approach?

Comment: It's a good practice to use View Models for many reasons but mostly because it keeps your domain model clean by keeping concerns like Validation, Presentation Logic, Data Formatting in your View Models and separate from your Domain entities, besides they prevent [over-posting attacks](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2012/03/11/complete-guide-to-mass-assignment-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx). So, I don't think there's a better approach to pass data between your controllers and views.

Answer (score 0):

While MVC default project template offer just one model folder, thus implicitly presenting the idea  that models are one thing, in fact There are three types of data models potentially involved in an ASP.NET MVC application:

```
 - Domain model objects will be passed from and to a middle tier services interfacing with databases. 

- View Model objects are those that the Controller pass to the View.

- Input model objects are those that the default modelBinder or some  custom modelBinder  generates from the view, although in many cases the input models are the same view model objects.
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. one question remains: Is it good approach what i am doing here, trying to get this separation of concerns?, you know, i could make reference to my domain class in my controller to create a list of type <my domain class> to receive the results and that's it. I would not need to map these two classes. (domain class - view class).?Is there another better approach?

Comment: Having View models distinct to Domain model is on your advantage. Separating your data that way you can do DataAnnotations to your ViewModels that are not relevant to Domain models and so leverage ModelState.IsValid on the [httpPost] ,also  your domain object could contain properties filled with data generated by the business logic side of your app and not generated by user input  and last but not least domain models can contain data not meant to be show to the user.

Comment: Thanks. That's clear now. I really appreciate your help.